# Javascript trimming a link with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, wordpress

I use a wordpress plugin in my new project. its slideshow-gallery. When I change setting it wont show images in colorbox mode.

I change some code in that plugin but I stuck in my codes.
my problem is; plugin is use thimbthumb so I cant fetch images. how can I fetch images source ?

example:
http://eskavalve.com/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-gallery/vendors/timthumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/slideshow-gallery/6.png&w=285&h=210&q=100&a=t

like that link. I want to fetch this link. >>>>> wp-content/uploads/slideshow-gallery/6.png

p.s: I can use only  javascript

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simple regex like

```
var string = 'http://eskavalve.com/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-gallery/vendors/timthumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/slideshow-gallery/6.png&w=285&h=210&q=100&a=t';
var part = string.match(/src=(.*?)(?=$|&)/)[1];
```

It takes out string after `src=` until end of the string or `&`

Comment: Don't think you need the `$|` part. Seems to work fine with just `/src=(.*?)(?=&)/`.  It goes to end of string because of the `.*` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Or using not &:

```
var link = 'http://eskavalve.com/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-gallery/vendors/timthumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/slideshow-gallery/6.png&w=285&h=210&q=100&a=t';
var part = link.match(/src=([^&]*)/)[1];
console.log(part);
```